# Путь для установки Download manager

Tags: java

Как мне указать путь для директории, в которую будет установлен файл через Download Manager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Покопавшись в интернете, нашёл ответ на свой вопрос

Нужный метод: `request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(directory, filename);`

Пример:

```
 Request request = new Request(Uri.parse(URL_ADDRESS));
        request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(3);
        request.setTitle((CharSequence)"Download");
        request.setDescription((CharSequence)"The file is downloading..");
        request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
        request.setNotificationVisibility(1);
//File is saving to "Download"
        request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, 
FILE_NAME+FILE_EXTENSION);
```